# How do I defer a subscription in Android (Google Play Billing)?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, subscription

I have implemented an in app subscription in Android, it all works fine, I even have a 30 day free trial to begin with.

I have a referral feature in the app, so when a certain value in the database reaches 10 (i.e. 10 referrals) - I want to give the user a free 30 day subscription.

I have had a look around and think deferring the subscription by the desired amount would the solution. However, I have no idea how to go about this. The api docs dont seem to be Android-specific, and I cant find a proper tutorial anywhere. Any help massively appreciated.

Already tried looking at the docs - https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/defer

Do I just make the http request listed there? I was hoping for a nice in-built call I can make.

I simply wish for:

when a certain variable == 10, to defer, or increase the subscription length by 30 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheers mate.

Currently [this](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/defer) is the only official way to do it. You may try to find some third party library on github, but I would not count on it.

I would recommend you to use [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) and create this call by yourself.

Maybe in (the) future Google will include this method as a default one in its billing library though - we just have to wait)

Hope it helps, mate.

Comment: Looks like this is the only way indeed - thank you for your answer. Do you have any idea if it is possible to get a valid `expiryTimeMillis` to use in the api call? 

It seems I would have to make one API call to first get this value, and then the `POST` call to defer the subscription, but surely the time it takes to do this would then make the `expiryTimeMillis` invalid, as it will have changed by this time.

See the text "If the current expiry time for the subscription is not the value specified here, the deferral will not occur".

Thank You

Comment: Nope - your conclusion is based on the wrong assumptions. ```expiryTimeMillis``` - is not a countdown of milliseconds left till the end of subscription, it is a date and time representation of when it should end. So the ```startTimeMillis``` and ```expiryTimeMillis``` in Purchases.subscriptions endpoint both are ordinary timestamps and they are not changing over time. Except if you change them of course. Hope it helps